# Rspec 3.3 - test that a method has been called on an instance variable in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec3

I have an Appointments controller that looks like this:

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
    if @appointment.update_attributes(params[:appointment])
      @appointment.update_order_time_remaining
      redirect_to order_path(@appointment.order)
    else
     redirect_to :back
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to write a test that verifies that `update_order_time_remaining` is called on @appointment. Test looks like:

```
RSpec.describe AppointmentsController, :type => :controller do
  describe "PUT update" do
    it "calls update_order_time_remaining" do
      @appt = Appointment.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:appointment))
      expect(controller.instance_variable_get :@appointment).to receive(:update_order_time_remaining)
      put :update, appointment: {status: 'confirmed'}, id: @appt.id
    end
  end
end
```

The code has been simplified a bit. I have other appointment controller tests that are passing just fine, but I cannot get this test to pass. I keep getting the failure message:

`Failure/Error: expect(controller.instance_variable_get :@appointment).to receive(:update_order_time_remaining)
(#<Appointment:0x00000009044b48>).update_order_time_remaining(*(any args))
    expected: 1 time with any arguments
    received: 0 times with any arguments`

I have also tried using `assigns(:appointment)` instead of `controller.instance_variable_get :@appointment`

## UPDATE

I got the test to pass using this code:

```
it "calls update_order_time_remaining" do
  @appt = Appointment.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:appointment))
  expect_any_instance_of(Appointment).to receive(:update_order_time_remaining)
  put :update, appointment: {durations: ['60'], status: 'confirmed'}, id: @appt.rand_id
end
```

This seems kind of inexact, but do you think it's sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

It may also be fine.

Another options is to make Appointment return exactly the same instance, ex:

```
expect(Appointment).to receive(:find).with(appt.rand_id).and_return(appt)
expect(appt).to receive(:update_order_time_remaining)
```

(no need to use instance variable in test in this case)

In this case you can use `mock`(instead of actual created record) to make tests faster.

Why do you create Appointment with such a strange code?
`Appointment.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:appointment))`

If there's built record will be invalid it won't be saved to DB, but you will not know it. It may lead to odd test failures.

1) FactoryGirl has create method, which is shorter and will fail if there're errors

2) Better use bang version `create!` to have failure if your record is invalid

**UPD** Example test:

```
it "calls update_order_time_remaining" do
  appointment = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:appointment)
  expect(Appointment).to receive(:find).with(appointment.rand_id).and_return(appointment)
  expect(appointment).to receive(:update_order_time_remaining)
  put :update, appointment: {durations: ['60'], status: 'confirmed'}, id: appointment.rand_id
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @faron. Can you explain a bit on how to set up a mock for this. Would I set up a mock Appointment class and tell it to return appt? Also, yes, that was a weird create implementation. I was incorrectly under the impression that FactoryGirl.create made an OpenStruct... not sure why I thought that, but thanks for correcting me.